# I can't get informations from body-parser. On MacOs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

app.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var ejsLayout = require('express-ejs-layouts');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname, '/app_server/views'));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(ejsLayout);
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
require('./app_server/route/routeManager')(app);

app.listen(8000);
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ctrlLogin = require('../controller/loginController');
router.get('/',ctrlLogin.index);
router.post('/',ctrlLogin.indexpost);

module.exports = router;
```

controller.js

```
module.exports.indexpost = function(req,res){

console.log(req.body);
res.render('login');
}
```

I run nodemon app.js in terminal then I write requests but I can't get response from body-parser

Comment: Where are you exactly having a problem? Can you explain a bit more

Comment: In terminal I get [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
{}

Comment: Okay that happens when you change something in the code you are monitoring

Comment: I set there req.body but when I request I can't get response from body parser. Can you look up app.js and controller.js

Comment: What can I do then?

Comment: There is nothing logging on the console?

Comment: Yes you're right. I said console.log(req.body) but it's nothing logging just a empty string

Comment: Are you sure while making request you are really sending something in the body that it should log?

Comment: See your body-parser is properly configured

Comment: Check the thing I mentioned in the second last comment and let me know the status, I can help you with this.

Comment: yes I am sure my body parser configured

Comment: maybe I must write another thing to controller.js.  I write console.log(req.body);

Comment: What are you sending as data which you want to get logged on the console as body?

Comment: module.exports.indexpost = function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body)
    res.render('login');
}

Comment: I get that, I want to know what exactly are you sending as data to this particular route, that you want to get logged

Comment: Or you are trying to achieve something else and I am not getting that, can you explain to me a bit more about what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: I created a login page and I want to get informations from there but I can't get

Comment: You are posting the data as the JSON and same you want to log it to the console?

Comment: Can you share the code in CodePen or so, it would be a bit easy for me to debug it